# How do I remove the keyboard after I finish an activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-softkeyboard, history

I have an activity that users type inside and then click the ok button. When it is finished, the activity closes and goes back to the old activity but the soft keyboard is still on the screen! I've tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` and

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

But it does nothing.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In OnPause of your activity, you should do the following

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Where et is an instance of your EditText.

Comment: I've used this approach to implement my "Search Activity" within "Start activity for result" to hide keyboard. Thank you!

Comment: I've a similar situation where an activity opened by an SDK is not dismissing the keyboard when the activity finishes. I end up with a keyboard that's covering half my activity. Any idea how to dismiss the keyboard shown by a different activity?

Comment: What if you have multiple EditText ? how do you know from which to call getWindowToken() ?

Comment: i used `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);`, when there are more than one EditText on my layout.