# Android keyboard still visible after return from Email Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity (extending Activity) running in a TabHost. I launch the Android Email client from a user action.  If I hit the "Discard" button in the Email client, the Email client exits but leaves the on-screen keyboard visible.

I have no EditTexts on my application so not sure why the keyboard stays up. I've tried several iterations of [How do I remove the keyboard after I finish an activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339515/how-do-i-remove-the-keyboard-after-i-finish-an-activity) however no luck. Any thoughts?

code sample

```
package com.test.launchmail;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class myEmail extends Activity
{
    private final String TAG = "** Email **";


    public static void send (Context ctx, String addy, String subject, String body)
    {
        // check to make sure the entry has a phone number
        try
        {
            // use the builtin chooser for users mail app
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

            sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String [] {addy});
            sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            ctx.startActivity (Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send via which Application?"));

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText (ctx, "No activity was found to handle this action",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostResume()
    {
       // This executes, but keyboard still visible. 
        Log.d ("myEmail", "hiding");
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow (mainApp.tabHost.getCurrentTabView ().getApplicationWindowToken (),imm.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

       super.onResume ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Good grief how irritating. I searched around all day and finally found the answer buried under a thread of 29 different ways to do it. Everyone claiming success with a different variation of InputMethodManager. For what it's worth, this one worked for me [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard/9494042#9494042).

It hope one day there is a standard API call to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put into your Manifest file in the desired activity (the one that you don't the keyboard to be shown) this: `windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Comment: ziziana -- I've added stateHidden as well as stateAlwaysHidden, still no luck.

Comment: @wufoo Maybe you will lucky if you use "stateAlwaysHidden"

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to do the following before navigating to the email activity:

1. make sure the keyboard was hidden on my app's screen (popular stackoverflow method used)
2. and most importantly, make sure the EditText on the screen no longer had focus.  `contactSearchView.clearFocus()`